# How to use defdelegate in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Could somebody provide a simple example for `defdelegate`.  I couldn't find any, making it hard to understand.

```elixir
defmodule Dummy do
  def hello, do: "hello from dummy"
end
```

I get `undefined function world/0` for the below:

```elixir
defmodule Other do
  defdelegate hello, to: Dummy, as: world
end
```

I would like to delegate `Other.world` to `Dummy.hello`

Comment: In https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex you can find defdelegate split(binary), to: String.Break

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Two things:

1. You got the name and `as:` wrong. `as:` should contain the name of the function in the target module and the first argument should be the name to define in the current module.
2. The argument to `as` needs to be an atom.

Final working code:

```elixir
defmodule Dummy do
  def hello, do: "hello from dummy"
end
    
defmodule Other do
  defdelegate world, to: Dummy, as: :hello
end
    
IO.puts Other.world
```

Output:

```sh
hello from dummy
```

Comment: How to do a defdelegate on private function?

Comment: @JuzerAli you don't. Private methods are only meant to be used within a module, so if you feel the need to delegate to a private method, your design is flawed.